# Create folder and move documents inside that folder using SPD workflow 2010

Tags: 2010, document-library, designer-workflow

I am trying to create a folder inside a library which will hold newly updated documents from another library? I am unable to create a simple folder with workflow, how can this be done?

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/search?q=workflow+create+folder

Answer (score 4):

**I am unable to create a simple folder with workflow, how can this be done?**

You can add a Folder via workflow in Document Library by creating a new list item and specifying `Content type ID` to **Folder**

**Steps**

- Edit your workflow ,
- From Action > Add Create List Item.
- Select your doc library that you need to add your folder.
- Add `Content type ID` > select folder
- At path and name Specify path & name, you can specify it dynamically as mentioned at [creating-folders-and-sub-folders-using-sharepoint-2010-designer-workflow](http://www.getinthesky.com/2012/08/creating-folders-and-sub-folders-using-sharepoint-2010-designer-workflow/)

[image]

For more details check this video [Create folder using workflow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=7-7kqdCA1ys) to create a folder and subfolder in your doc library via workflow

Comment: Hi @Madhav you are welcome , glad to hear it's helped you , so should you please set it as answer and upvote it . Thanks

Comment: actually i'd love to do it but it guides to create folder only, the document moving part is missing,i already upvoted it when i found it as helpfull ,but if i will mark it as answer it will missguide needy people in future

Comment: you are right my bro , and thank you for your appreciation , I only request this because you have mentioned at your question  "I am unable to create a simple folder with workflow" and when find your comment "Thanks it helped me for creating folder inside library" I thought it's totally solved your issue based on your question request , anyway it's nice to talk with you :) thanks again .

Comment: Thanks for undersanding ,actully i resolved this issue will post Answer soon when will have that much free time .... :)

Comment: @Madhav Do you have time now? I don't need it, but it'd help to close this question out.

Comment: yes i do have time sir.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The following solution is only viable for SharePoint Designer Workflow 2013 as there is no OOTB action for REST Calls in SharePoint Designer Workflow 2010!

folder creation part is completed into the answer posted by [M.Qassas](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/53462/m-qassas) and this answer contains only copying documents to that folder from another library here I am using Rest API's and that s as per below snap
[image]

Comment: Is this a SharePoint 2013 workflow? OP requested SharePoint 2010 workflow, so not sure this would work.

Comment: Hi Madhav, Nulldata is right, this is no SPD2010 Workflow as there are no REST Calls or something similar avaiable. As you stated above by yourself you don't want to irritate the readers, so please correct this in your answer and mark it that this is to be done with SPD2013 Workflows instead of SPD2010. Thanks in advance