# Using a workflow to automatically create document folders each time a new list entry is made

Tags: list, document-library, designer-workflow, column

I'm new to sharepoint developer, so I'm hoping someone is able to guide me (provide simple instructions!) on whether it's possible to create a workflow where once I enter a new item in a list, a new document folder is automatically created.

For example:
I have a list called "Client List" which contains various clients information (with columns of "Name of Entity" "Country" etc).  Rather than manually have to create a folder structure each time a new client is added to the list, I would like to run a workflow that creates a folder (and sub folders) in the "Client Folder" document library.

Ideally I would then like to have an auto generated link in the client list whereby a user can click to then see the various documents associated with that client.

Many thanks,

M.

Comment: This link may help you to create folder using workflow.https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/200406/create-folder-and-move-documents-inside-that-folder-using-spd-workflow-2010?rq=1