# Creating hyperlinks in a list using a workflow

Tags: workflow, library, hyperlink

I could use some help. To get this started, I am using Sharepoint Online through Office 365.

There are three lists in this Sharepoint site. Quotes, Pending Jobs, and Active Jobs. I did not create this Sharepoint site, I have just inherited it and am tasked with improving it and adding to it. I do not know why there are three separate lists as opposed to just three views of one list, and there are other things built around the fact there are three lists so I cannot restart and make it all one list.

So, there are three lists. Workflows are used to bring quotes to pending jobs, and then pending jobs to active jobs. Initially the user was attaching documents to the list item in quotes. The attachments were not surviving the workflow.

I thought it would be better to use folders instead of attaching documents right to the list items. I set up a workflow that would create a folder in a library on creation of an item in the Quotes list. This folder would have the same name as the quote. I was able to get this working no problem. I wanted to then have the URL for the new folder placed back into a field in the quote list item. The field I am attempting to place the URL in to is called 'Link" and it is a single line of text type of field. I have experimented some with using the hyperlink type of field as well. I have not had success with either.

Essentially my question is this, how do I get the URL of the new folder and place it back into a field in the quote. And, is this even the best way to approach this problem?

To better explain my question I have created some visual aids. I highly recommend checking them out to get a full grasp of the situation. They can be found at the following link https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsZE6.jpg

Thank you for your time and I hope there is a solution out there. I know this thread, [Using a workflow to automatically create document folders each time a new list entry is made](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/242160/using-a-workflow-to-automatically-create-document-folders-each-time-a-new-list-e) , asks essentially the same question but no one ever answered the hyperlink part.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use a Multiple Lines of Text(Enhanced Rich Text) column and use the "Set field in current item" action. The field needed to be set to an html thing. Looks like this:

```
<a href="reddit.com">I Love Reddit</a>
```

Using the correct column and the html wording I was able to hyperlink correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go back to using a hyperlink type of field, you have to structure the data a little bit differently.

Create a string variable in your workflow, and fill it in with:

link, description

For example:
https://yoursitename/DocumentLibrary/FolderName, FolderName

The link first, then a comma and a space. The space is important
Everything after that is the description that shows up.

Use your set variable for the hyperlink list field and fill it in with your string variable.